# How to group command-line arguments in python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

```
import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Tool to keep archiving tar files")  
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", dest="action", choices=("start", "stop", "list"), help="start/stop/list the directories to be monitored", default="list", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", dest="type", choices=("a", "b"), help="Type of spooler job", default=None)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", dest="path", help="Absolute path of the directory to be monitored", default=None)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--codeline", dest="codeline", choices=("x","y","z"), default=None, required=True)
parser.add_argument("-r", "--release", dest="release", help="Directory path gets assigned automatically based on the release", default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

In the above code, if the action is given as start/stop, type and one of path/release are mandatory inputs. Is there any way to do this in add_argument method itself?

Additional info:
If the action is given as "list", none of the other options are required. For eg., **"script.py -a list"** should work. 
 Only if the action is given as start/stop, the other options are required. For eg., **"script.py -a start"** should throw error. **"script.py -a start -t a -p /tmp -c x"** or **"script.py -a start -t b -r rr -c y"** should work

Comment: You will likely need to use a subparser: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `add_subparsers(dest='action')` and create `list`, `start`, `stop` subparsers, each with the desired arguments (none for `list`), the following inputs will work as desired.  (Note `-a` is not used).

```
script.py list
script.py start  # fail with insufficient arguments
script.py start -t a -p /tmp -c x
script.py start -t b -r rr -c y
```

---

to expand on my suggestion:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Tool to keep archiving tar files")
sub = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
sp1 = sub.add_parser('start')
sp2 = sub.add_parser('stop')
sp3 = sub.add_parser('list')
#parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", dest="action", choices=("start", "stop", "list"), help="start/stop/list the directories to be monitored", default="list", required=True)
for sp in [sp1,sp2]:
    sp.add_argument("-t", "--type", dest="type", choices=("a", "b"), help="Type of spooler job", default=None)
    sp.add_argument("-p", "--path", dest="path", help="Absolute path of the directory to be monitored", default=None)
    sp.add_argument("-c", "--codeline", dest="codeline", choices=("x","y","z"), default=None, required=True)
    sp.add_argument("-r", "--release", dest="release", help="Directory path gets assigned automatically based on the release", default=None)

for astr in [
    'list',
    'start -t a -p /tmp -c x',
    'start -t b -r rr -c y',
    'start']:
    print parser.parse_args(astr.split())
```

results are:

```
Namespace(action='list')
Namespace(action='start', codeline='x', path='/tmp', release=None, type='a')
Namespace(action='start', codeline='y', path=None, release='rr', type='b')
usage: stack19510774.py start [-h] [-t {a,b}] [-p PATH] -c {x,y,z}
                              [-r RELEASE]
stack19510774.py start: error: argument -c/--codeline is required
```

If `-c` does not make sense for `stop`, then omit it from its argument setup.

There are lots of SO questions about using subparsers.

Comment: Above works. But **"script.py stop -t a -p /tmp"** doesn't work. Appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 1):

Just create an [argument group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argument-groups):

```
parser = ArgumentParser(description="Tool to keep archiving tar files")

group = parser.add_argument_group('some group')
group.add_argument("-a", "--action", dest="action", choices=("start", "stop", "list"), help="start/stop/list the directories to be monitored", default="list", required=True)
group.add_argument("-t", "--type", dest="type", choices=("a", "b"), help="Type of spooler job", default=None)
group.add_argument("-p", "--path", dest="path", help="Absolute path of the directory to be monitored", default=None)
group.add_argument("-r", "--release", dest="release", help="Directory path gets assigned automatically based on the release", default=None)

parser.add_argument("-c", "--codeline", dest="codeline", choices=("x","y","z"), default=None, required=True)
```

Comment: If the action is given as "list", none of the other options are required. For eg., script.py -a list. Only if the action is given as start/stop, the other options are required. For eg., "script.py -a start" should throw error. "script.py -a start -t a -p /tmp -c x" or "script.py -a start -t b -r rr -c y" should work

Comment: @Hema: That sounds like a potential sub-command, then; `script.py start` would be the sub-command, and the rest are then arguments to that sub-command and can all be made required.